# How to fix bad topology?

Tags: edges, subdivision-surface, topology, retopology, remesh

I am trying to recreate a relief surface. The result from the displacing modifier was not good so I decided to create it manually from a subdivided plane. I have deleted some edges and connected others, deleted and created faces trying to fix my topology it got a bit better but I am stuck with this crap [image]

I know that I caused this by dissolving and reconnecting vertices. I tried to use the retopology modifier but it didn't help out either.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mesh has inverted normals and hidden faces that are not quad:

[image]

Hidden faces can be revealed in edit mode with <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>H</kbd>. Delete them.

Once done, recheck the normal and if need correct them (either <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>N</kbd> to recalculate automatically, or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>N</kbd> to force inverted).

Comment: Thank you. I have forgotten that face when trying to clean the mesh. Everything went well!